# Find with multiple extension does not work with -exec

Tags: find

I am using a find command this way:

```
find ./my_path -name "*.ext1" -exec echo {} \;
```

And it would work.

Now with multiple extensions, the following command would display several files :

```
find ./my_path -name "*.ext1" -o -name "*.ext2"
```

But when using `-exec`:

```
find ./my_path -name "*.ext1" -o -name "*.ext2" -exec echo {} \;
```

No files are displayed.
What am I doing wrong, shouldn't it display just the same files as my second example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to group the filters:

```
find ./my_path \( -name "*.ext1" -o -name "*.ext2" \) -exec echo {} \;
```